# Prettier adds multiple empty lines after JavaScript blocks wrongely

Tags: prettier, prettier-vscode, jsprettier

My prettier is adding extra empty lines after blocks in JavaScript. It is OK after first save and empty line is just one, but after second save it add another line, and after third save it add one more. It not adds more with further saves.

Example:

```
    function calcTempAmplitude(array1, array2) {

    for (temp of array2) 
        array1.push(temp);
    


    let max = array1[0];
    let min = array1[0];
    for (temp of array1) {
        if (typeof temp !== 'number') 
            continue;
        


        if (temp > max) 
            max = temp;
        


        if (temp < min) 
            min = temp;
        


    }
    // return(min <= 0) ? max + min : max - min;
    return max - min;
}
console.log(calcTempAmplitude(tempetures1, tempetures2));
```

how to solve this buggy behavior?

Comment: it seems a bug because I use same setting in a different device and it works correct over there!

Answer (score 0):

It fixed through reinstalling the Prettier extension!